# React Material UI Data Grid : Infinite Re-render when adding custom Data Grid Row

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I am using `MUI` `Data Grid` and I would want to make something like this with it:

[image]

I tried this:

```
    <Box
      sx={{
        padding: "16px",
      }}
    >
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        initialState={{
          pagination: {
            paginationModel: { page: 0, pageSize: 5 },
          },
        }}
        pageSizeOptions={[5, 10]}
        checkboxSelection={false}
        disableColumnMenu
        disableVirtualization
        columnHeaderHeight={48}
        rowHeight={48}
        slots={{
          row: (props) => {
            return (
              <Box>
                <GridRow {...props} />

                <Box>{"extra row below"}</Box>
              </Box>
            );
          },
        }}
      />
    </Box>
```

But it caused infinite re-render,

I also tried circumventing it, like `display: "flex, flexDirection: "column"` etc, but everytime the layout is showing 2x rows (`1x actual data row, 1x error row below`), it will trigger infinite re-rendering

[image]

Here is the link to the `codesandbox` showing the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/small-https-d8dm88?file=%2Fdemo.tsx%3A65%2C1-96%2C11